# TikZ scope options not working

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[fill=red, draw=green,text=blue]
      \node[fill=red, draw=green] at (0,0) {A};
      \node[text=black] at (2,0) {B};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My question is: Why do only the `text` option to the `\scope` environment work? (That is: I would like the B-node to have a red background and a green border, but as seen from the included image, nothing happens)
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding of how a `node` actually behaves. A node is not a `\path` in itself, per definition.

A `node` has its own name-space in terms of special keys which apply to it.

The reason is `\node` gets expanded to `\path node` and whatever is in the `scope` environment is *only* appended to `path`s. This means your code is equivalent to:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[fill=red, draw=green,text=blue]
    \node[fill=red, draw=green] at (0,0) {A};
    \path (2,0) node[text=black] {B};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which much clearer what is happening. Hence, you could do this:

```
  \begin{scope}[all/.style={fill=red, draw=green,text=blue},all,
       every node/.append style={all}]
```

to achieve what you want, `all` is then used every where, even on nodes.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation.. I think this point is not made very clear in the TikZ-documentation. As far as I can see, it is not mentioned in chapter 12.3, "Using scopes to structure a picture"

Answer (score 9):

The nodes do not inherit the path options. To make it work you can use

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={fill=red, draw=green,text=blue}]
      \node at (0,0) {A};
      \node[text=black] at (2,0) {B};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

then the resulting picture is

[image]

Comment: Thank you.. I was not aware of the difference between nodes and paths regarding `scope` options..